# respond to user actions in a django admin form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model which stores different types of data (discrete or continuous values) in one field (with the type in another). In a ModelForm for that model I have a ChoiceField to choose the data item, and either an ChoiceField or a DecimalField to set the item's value.

When I create the form I set the field for the value according to the item's type. But if I choose an item of a different type, I would like to immediately change the value field to match.

I can find no way to respond to a change while the form is still active, ie while the user is changing field values but has not clicked the Submit button. Is there some way to do that? Preferably staying in Python on the server, rather than browser-side coding it in javascript.

The choices for the ChoiceField are taken from the model, so they can't be hard coded anywhere.

Here is some code:

```
class FooProperty (models.Model):
    foo     = models.ForeignKey ('foos.Foo')
    prop    = models.ForeignKey ('foos.FooProperty')
    value   = models.DecimalField (max_digits=15, decimal_places=6) # is an EnumValue id in the case of discrete values.

class FooPropertyForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FooProperty
        fields = ['prop', 'value']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super (FooPropertyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if hasattr (self.instance, 'prop'):
            kind = self.instance.prop.units.kind
            if kind.id != 1:
                values = [(v.id, v.name) for v in EnumValues.objects.filter (kind=kind.id)]
                self.fields ['value'] = forms.ChoiceField (choices=values, required=True)
                self.initial['value'] = int(self.instance.value) # using initial= above doesn't work.
            else:
                # keep the default field.
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar polymorphic model that stores different types of values (str, int, decimal, etc) based on its type.

Could you clarify your question a bit? You say "if I choose an item of a different type".  Do you mean by changing a form field in your browser, or in your code?

I'll assume you mean the former. **There is no way to respond to live form changes in Python without some sort of asynchronous communication from the client side**.

In my app, it's a 2-step process:

1. The user to chooses a type
2. On the client side, a change handler on that type field triggers a call to fetch the type-specific form fields. There's a separate Django view that instantiates a separate form with a bunch of type-specific fields and logic.

```js
var $kind = $('#kind');

$kind.on('change', fetchFormFieldsForKind);

function fetchFormFieldsForKind() {
  var kind = $kind.val();
  $.get(
    "{% url 'form_fields_for_kind' %}?kind=" + $kind.val(),

    function (response) {
      newFieldsHtml = response.newFieldsHtml || '';

      // Replace all following sibling form fields with the new ones
      // (each field is wrapped by a div with Bootstrap class form-group)
      $kind.closest('.form-group').find('~ .form-group').remove();
      $kind.after(newFieldsHtml);

      // or replace the whole form with a rendered ModelForm
    }
  );
}
```

For completeness, that Django view would look something like this:

```
def form_fields_for_kind(request, kind):
    """
    Given the string 'kind', return a rendered form that contains 
    any type-specific fields.
    """
    form = YourForm(kind=kind) 
    content = form.as_p()
    return HttpResponse(content, 'text/html')
```